# jQuery UI Dialog Read-Only / Edit Form with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table of data. I would like the user to be able to select a row and view the details in a jquery modal dialog.

I have this working fine. Based on permissions, the user may be able to edit the data in the modal. In this case, I would like to present a button to switch to "edit" mode.

Would it make sense for this button to load a new partial Edit view into the modal? or should I just combine the Read-only and Edit forms into a single view thats loaded intially and use javascript/css to hide the Edit Form until needed?

Comment: Simply include the references to jQuery ui library.
call $("#details).Load('Controller/Action/Index/xx').Dialog() when your link in your grid is clicked and voila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more of a design question as long as you don't send the Edit Form to the client side and only hide in case when the user doesn't have the permission to edit it.

Otherwise you'll be better of discussing this with the stakeholders.

In my personal opinion, I simply hate Modals. They just tend to be very overwhelming but that's just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you waste network traffic by downloading both views together? I would use separate ajax call to download edit form. 
1. If your edit form is large in html size, you would waste traffic when downloading together (User may never press the edit button)
2. If edit form is relatively small, switching to it via ajax downloading would be almost transparent to user - no extra timing, no extra traffic waste